# Contour integration with essential singularity at infinity

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

I would like to evaluate the integral

$$\int_C \frac{e^{-(x^2-a^2)}}{x^2-a^2}\,dx$$

by integration over the complex plane. There are two poles at $x=\pm a$ on the real axis, which I can shift to $x=\pm a\mp i\varepsilon$ (and later consider the limit $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$), to integrate over the real axis. So my contour $C$ goes along the real axis from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and then along a semicircle centered at $0$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

This is the standard procedure for [Feynman propagators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Feynman_propagator), which look similar to my integral, just without the exponential function. However, the exponential function has an essential singularity on the imaginary axis for $x^2\rightarrow-\infty$ (edited in response to comment).

How do I perform a contour integration, which involves poles both on the real axis and an essential singularity at infinity on the imaginary axis? Can I simply apply the residue theorem for the poles at $x=\pm a$ and ignore the singularity of the exponential function? In this case, the integration would simply yield the result $1/(\pm 2a)$ from the residues at $x=\pm a$. But shouldn't also the exponential function and its singularity affect the result of the integration?

Comment: I don't see how that exponential function yields poles. The exponential function is entire. Perhaps you mean to say that there is an *essential* singularity at infinity, but that's not a problem because you treat the integral as an "internal domain" contour integral. Maybe you mean that the exponential function creates poles when you do the shifting or something?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right, the exponential function does not yield poles, but an essential singularity. Can I simply apply the residue theorem for the poles at $x=\pm a$ and ignore the singularity of the exponential function? In this case, the integral would simply yield $1/(\pm 2a)$ from the residues at $x=\pm a$. But shouldn't also the exponential function and its singularity affect the result of the integration?

Comment: The singularity at infinity doesn't contribute to the integration directly...but the integral over the arc doesn't converge which is really the problem.

Comment: Does this imply the the integral is not solvable?

Comment: It means the contour you chose won't do you any good (unless the shifting fixes the problem somehow, but I don't think it does).

Comment: Which better contour could I choose in order to evaluate the integral? (If I shift the poles away from the real axis by $\pm i\varepsilon$ and choose a contour over the real axis and the semicircle, I go around these poles, right? <- in response to the previous version of your comment.) The shifting $-a^2$ can't fix the problem, I think.

Comment: I see another problem: the singularities on the real axis at $\pm a$ are not integrable in the normal sense (only as Cauchy p.v.).

Comment: Perhaps my explanation above was misleading - the singularities are at $\pm a \mp i\varepsilon$. And I make two separate integrations, one over the semicircle in the upper half plane and one over the semicircle in the lower half plane. In this case, they should be integrable, right?

Comment: Yes, but this way of regularizing is the same as using the Cauchy PV.

Comment: Okay. Can I solve the integral by chosing a different contour, e.g., a rectangle, which avoids the singularity at infinity?